# Difference between "stick with" and "stick to"?

Tags: differences, verbs, prepositions

The more I think about it the more confused I get:

One good example is [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/63297-stick-stick.html):

> Hmm. Maybe something like this. It's the end of the day and things
>   didn't go well. We're meeting to talk about what we'll do tomorrow.
>   Should we stick with the original plan or try something new?
>
> We're at work, and I wander by to see how everyone is doing. You think
>   that you'd like to try something difference. "Stick to the plan for
>   now," I say.
>
> So maybe while planning - stick with, and while doing - stick to?
>
> I'm speculating ... sometimes the more you think about something the
>   harder it is to remember.

Is there a difference between

> to stick with something/somebody

and

> to stick to something/somebody

...and if so could you please give examples that make the different usages clear?

Comment: @Downvoter: It is good practice here to give reasons for the downvote and hints how to make the question better - thank you!

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations in your question if they're not relevant. "please" is just a character longer than "pls." and comes across as a lot better

Comment: Have you just thought about the phrases, or have you thought about actual uses or dictionary definitions? We really need to know what confuses you, and whether you have exhausted ordinary references.

Comment: @StoneyB: Indeed I have and the bottom line is - as I said - that both seem to be acceptable in many circumstances yet there seem to be subtle differences which seem to elude me.

Comment: Then you need to incorporate your findings in your question, so we don't have twenty people repeating your work.

Comment: @StoneyB: Very helpful comment - thank you. I included one very striking example from my research.

Comment: Thank you. I've now upvoted your question, and hope the downvoters will revisit it and rescind their votes.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the abbreviations as well. I rescinded my own previous vote, and upvoted you.

Comment: And **she's  grown up in the sticks**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On the forum you [**linked**](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/63297-stick-stick.html) to, a long catalog of uses was posted at 20-Mar-2008, 08:27. I think that posting makes clear that

1. there is **no difference** between the two phrases in the senses of "continuing to support/accompany/practise/adhere [figuratively] to": *stick to/with the plan*, *stick to/with me*, *stick to/with your principles*

ANOTHER EDIT: You may find one preposition used *more often* with any particular object stuck to—see bib's response—but this doesn't exclude using the other.

1. only *stick to* may be used to signify "cause to adhere to": *stick the poster to the wall* but **not** *stick the poster with the wall*.
2. only *stick with* may be used to signify "impose a (relative) burden upon": *he stuck me with the bill* or *she got the fellowship, I was stuck with an assistantship*, but *to* won't work in these.

One more "stick to" idiom occurs to me: *stick **it** to [someone]", meaning "inflict excessive (physical, emotional, financial &c) pain upon": *They had him cornered and really stuck it to him*.

EDIT: And another: *Stick to [one's] guns*, although it fits use 1 above, is a fixed idiom; *stick **with** your guns* would mean "continue to accompany your artillery".

Comment: Agreed there's *no difference* in sense #1. But as I suspected, there seems to be a preference in some idiomatic contexts - it's mostly [**to** with *the plan*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stick+to+the+plan%2Cstick+with+the+plan&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but the other way round [**with** *the program/programme*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stick+to+the+program%2Cstick+with+the+program%2Cstick+to+the+programme%2Cstick+with+the+programme&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Hmmm ... looks like BE *to ... programme* was picked up in AE and subsequently evolved into *with ... program*. I wonder if this reflects pressure from [***get** with the program*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+to+the+program%2Cget+with+the+program%2Cget+to+the+programme%2Cget+with+the+programme&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)?

Comment: +1 But disagree slightly with @FumbleFingers; I think *with the plan* is softer, less exclusionary than *to the plan*.

Comment: @bib  FF's depending on NGrams, so you have to quarrel with his methodology. **I** think these differences are mostly idiolectal or random or both.

Comment: @StoneyB: I never got as far as wondering *why*, but it's invariably *get **with the program***, (not *get with the **plan***), so that's credible. On the other hand, it's normally ***stick to** the point*, not *stick **with** the point*. I agree many such differences in preposition are idiolectal / random, but statistically those differences are "real" (there really are 50K *to the plan*, and only 10K *with the plan*). But I do now agree with bib - *in certain other contexts* that you didn't cover, *with/to* can both occur *with different meanings*.

Comment: And don't forget that I am stuck with you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Real, but not constitutive (yet). Yeah, basically there's too much variance to generalize, even as little as I have.

Comment: @Noah  That's 2. But there's also stuck *on* you.

Answer (score 6):

The phrases *stick with* and *stick to* can both mean continue to support, participate or favor. However there are differences in application.

When talking about an activity, a plan, a tangible or intangible object, the term can have subtly different meanings:

> I'm sticking with swimming.
>   I'm sticking with the plan.
>   I'm sticking with apples.
>   I'm sticking with economics.

They all mean *I will continue to play, follow, eat or study the focus of my sticking*.

However, the phase, *sticking to* suggest that I'm persevering, but *limiting* my attention.

> I am sticking to swimming.
>   I am sticking to apples.

This connotes that I will be swimming instead of going out for track, yearbook or some other activity. The pie will not contain pears, just apples.

With regard to people, the phrase *sticking with* conveys ongoing support.

> I'm sticking with fluoride toothpaste.
>   I'm sticking with Grover Cleveland.

Both convey commitment, to the dental plan or candidate.

However, *sticking to* with regard to people, means *stay close, physically*

> I am sticking to my kids in their after school activities.
>   As a parole officer, I am sticking to my parolees like glue.
>   Oh you can't scare me, I'm stickin' to the union.

And, as Anita said to Maria in *West Side Story*

> A boy like that who'd kill your brother . . . 
>   Stick to your own kind

Both exclusionary and staying close.

Comment: These are *tendencies* rather than *rules*. For 'plan' see FumbleFingers' comment on my post. Google "sticking to/with my kids", you get *with*:5 *to*:0 true hits. And Woody Guthrie's Union Maid sang "You can't scare me, I'm sticking to the union!" . . . but see my Edit.

Comment: @StoneyB my memory failed me on Woody's locution. I guess he's holding the union very close. Safer when the Pinkertons show up.

Comment: @StoneyB revised to reflect your helpful observation.

Comment: When my boy was little the toothpaste mostly stuck to him...

Comment: Stick 'em up! Bib

Comment: I upvoted StoneyB's partly for examples where there's no difference, which imho includes, for example, *the plan*. But I now recognise that something like *stick to swimming* can imply *exclusively focus on*, where *with* might imply *doffedly continue with*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes, I launched into this too focused on the "core" overlap. That's why I've upvoted bib's answer; and why we have to keep *all* the answers around. (PS is that *do**gg**edly*?)

Comment: @StoneyB: Absolutely agree your thinking - and yes, unusually (for me!?) that was a typo. We do indeed need both answers, so I'll respond to yours here by saying that *stick **with** your guns* could mean *continue to use guns* (or *your specific guns*) as opposed to alternative weaponry. In principle *stick **to** your guns* could have various meanings - but ***only*** that form can have the metaphorical sense *principles*, and that's overwhelmingly the most common meaning.